# Excel Lookup with multiple output in one row

Tags: excel, lookup

I woould like to obtain this result:

[image]

I don't know what formula the cell B7 requires. it should be something like: for each `Ai` in `A1:A5`, if `Ai = A7` then `B7 = B7+Bi`

Is it possible with the Excel formulas? I don't want to use a macro because it is a file for the customer.

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: @Andreas B7 should be a collection of the B cells resoponding to A7 content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you basically just want to concatenate the text in column B if the value in column A is "A".

**Edit**: This formula will only work in Google Sheets:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:A5="A",B1:B5&" ",""))))`

**Edit**: In order to achieve the concatenation in Excel the process is slightly more complicated.

1. Enter the formula:

`=CONCATENATE(IF(A1:A4="A",B1:B4&" ",""))`

Depending on your regional setting (if your separator is `,`) you may need to use this formula instead:

`=TRANSPOSE(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:A4="A",B1:B4&" ","")))`

2. Instead of pressing enter, press F9. This will convert the formula into an array based on the criteria you entered. The strings you did want should now be in the array with a trailing space and values you did not want will appear as `""`.
3. You can now delete the curly braces (`{` and `}`) and add `TRIM(CONCATENATE(` to the beginning of the formula as well as two closing braces to the end `))`

The final formula should look something like:

`=TRIM(CONCATENATE("This ","","is a ","","","test. "))`

And will return:

> This is a test.

Comment: thanks but I have got `#VALUE!` what I wrote is: `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:A4="A";B1:B4;"")))`

Comment: Did you press `Ctrl` and `Enter` when entering the formula so that it is converted into an array formula? You can tell if you've done this correctly as the formula will be between `{` and `}`. You cannot manually enter `{` and `}`.

Comment: Also, you wanted to add a trailing space to your strings so they have spaces between each cell. So it should be: `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:A4="A";B1:B4&" ";"")))`

Comment: pressing `Ctrl` and `Enter` has no effects. it is Excel 2010, could this means something?

Comment: Hmm, I originally tested this on Google Sheets as I couldn't access Excel at the time, usually array formulas work the same on both systems however it would appear that this formula only works on Google Sheets using: `=ArrayFormula(TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:A4="A",B1:B4&" ",""))))` - I'll have a little play around on Excel and see if I can see why it only works on Google Sheets

Comment: Okay so it's slightly more long-winded but I'll update my answer to reflect what I've discovered @Stefano